# What should my JSON string look like in my Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, actionresult

in .NET MVC my action looks like:

```
public ActionResult TestAjax(string testID)
{

    return Content(@"{first: ""1"", second : ""2""}");
}
```

In my JavaScript I am doing:

```
function(data)
{
      alert(data.first);
}
```

I am getting `[object Object]` as the output, why is that?

Is my JSON string wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about letting the system deal with it:

```
    public ActionResult TestAjax(string testID)
    {
        return Json(new {first = 1, second = 2});
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a return with Json not Content

```
return Json(new { first = "1", second ="2" });
```